# how to fix xml issues after adt upgrade to 21.0.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I inherited an adt project that was developed in ganymede for java developers with adt plugin 20.0.3. I grabbed it from vss and imported it into my fresh install of adt 21.1.0 (the android bundle). The error log has 5 errors relating to unresolvable fields, but if I check the xml files for the project the fields are defined there. For some reason, they aren't being incorporated into the r.java for the project. Also, sometimes the console window complains about the project.properties file being missing, but it's in the top-level folder for the project.

I know a lot of people have had library project issues after an adt update, but this is happening within the project itself, not a referenced library.

I saw that deleting the gen folder has helped a lot of people in this case, but that didn't work.

I've also made sure that android.r.java is not in the imports, as well as cleaning the project.

I've imported the project both as an existing project and as a new project from existing code. Unresolvable fields result from both.

I had a teammate with a working install that could build, but he recently upgraded his plugin, and he has the same field errors now, too.

I'm not sure what to try from here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="common_error_check_status">A serious error has occured attempting to check application status. If this persists please try re-installing the application</string>
<string name="new_synchronization_messages_">You have new Synchronization Messages to view.</string>
<string name="synchronization_messages">Synchronization Messages</string>
</resources>
```

These are the strings that are not being included into the r.java for the project

Comment: You could try posting the resource files that are not working properly and indicating which specific items in those files are resulting in your "unresolvable fields" errors.

Comment: The specific errors from your "Problems" tab would be helpful.